# How to align picture in center and assign its size mode to auto size at the same time?

Tags: c#, winforms, panel, picturebox

I've got panel on the form for scrolling and picturebox on panel. When I assign SizeMode to CenterImage, scrolling doesn't work and when assigned to AutoSize then the picture isn't in center.

Is there any posibility for making both - to be able to scroll and picture to be placed in center?

Comment: Please post any code, try jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this simple Panel control that will handle the two requirements for you:

```
public class PanelImage : Panel {
  private Image image;

  public PanelImage() {
    this.DoubleBuffered = true;
    this.ResizeRedraw = true;
  }

  public Image Image {
    get { return image; }
    set { 
      image = value;
      if (image != null) {
        this.AutoScrollMinSize = image.Size;
      }
      this.Invalidate();
    }
  }

  protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
    e.Graphics.Clear(Color.White);
    if (image != null) {
      Point p = this.AutoScrollPosition;
      if (image.Width < this.ClientSize.Width) {
        p.X = (this.ClientSize.Width / 2) - (image.Width / 2);
      }
      if (image.Height < this.ClientSize.Height) {
        p.Y = (this.ClientSize.Height / 2) - (image.Height / 2);
      }
      e.Graphics.DrawImage(image, p);
    }
    base.OnPaint(e);
  }
}
```